# What is wrong with this sentence, and how should I fix it?

Tags: grammaticality, writing

I am proof-reading a short CV that details an employee's volunteer achievements. It will form part of an application for a committee position. The following sentence makes my brain itch, but I am having trouble deciding:

1. Why it sounds wrong (something with the tense, I think)
2. How it *should* be written

> I am fortunate to have been named as chair of this board shortly after I joined.

A little help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does "I am fortunate to have been named as chair of this board shortly after I joined it." fix the problem? If it does, can somebody explain why?

Comment: The "as" sounds out of place to me.  I think it would be better without it.

Comment: @John: good call. It definitely reads better without the "as".

Comment: Can anyone suggest a better title for this question? There could easily be thousands of questions with the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps

> I was fortunate to be named chair of this board shortly after I joined.

Or, if you don't want to emphasize how lucky you were,

> I was named chair of this board shortly after I joined.

Comment: Much better! The candidate *does* want to emphasize their luck, so the first sentence would be my first choice. Thank you.

Comment: +1, hehe, yes the second is better - modesty can easily be misread

Comment: @e.James Why, where they actually incompetent, but no-one realised?

Comment: @Tom: fair point, and quite funny when you put it that way! `:)` I am doing my best not to modify the *meaning* of the document. My role is to proof read the spelling, grammar and sentence structure.

Comment: @Tom: I passed on your interpretation to the author, and he has decided to go with the second sentence. He says thank you `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If it is tense/aspect that you are after, then maybe:

> I am fortunate to have been named as chair of this board shortly after I had joined.

The simple past of 'I joined' doesn't stick it in sequence very definitively (the 'shortly after' does of course).

Answer (score 1):

I was fortunate to be named chair of the board shortly after I joined.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have [the worm](http://www.sourcetext.com/grammarian/less-than-words-can-say/01.htm).  This sentence has an overly formal sound to it.  Try this:

> Fortunately, I became chair of the board once I joined.

Comment: +1 for your excellent link, although I feel that your sentence conveys a slightly different meaning from the original.